# sce trust as html does not print the HTML

Tags: javascript, angularjs

So i have the following HTML:

```
<p>Mmmhmmmmmm</p>
```

Very simple (however it does get more advanced than that but for the time being lets use the above as an example)

This value is stored in a `$scope` value: `$scope.selected.textContent`

And so in order to print it i used the following:

```
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
        {{$sce.trustAsHtml(selected.textContent)}}
    </div>
</div>
```

However it prints nothing.

if i do the following:

```
{{$sce.trustAsHtml(selected.textContent) || 'Hello'}}
```

It prints out `Hello`.

Can anyone tell me what im doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [ng-bind-html](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml) instead

```
<div class="col-xs-12" ng-bind-html="htmlHere">
</div>
```

and in your controller

```
$scope.htmlHere = $sce.trustAsHtml('<p>test</p>')
```

Comment: still does not print anything :S could it be that the element has an ng-if attribute? (the parent element has ng-if but this turns true once something is selected)

Comment: Is there a way to do that but with one way binding instead of using ng-bind?